# PyCurl Install not successful

Tags: python, macos, python-2.6, pycurl

While trying to install pycurl in my system (MAC OS X), I am getting the following error. No idea how to solve it. Please help !!!

```
   nsh$ sudo easy_install pycurl
   Searching for pycurl
   Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/
   Reading http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/
   Reading http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/
   Best match: pycurl 7.19.0
   Downloading http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz
   Processing pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz
   Running pycurl-7.19.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-tU3r7x/pycurl-7.19.0 /egg-dist-tmp-XBXPV8
   Using curl-config (libcurl 7.19.7)
   unable to execute gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
   error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
    nsh$
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to use:

```
# sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" pip install pycurl
```

But before that, install Xcode. Now it's free.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should try installing `gcc-4.2`?

Answer (score 0):

This *might* work, depending on whether or not you actually have gcc-4.2 installed.

```
cd /usr/bin
ln -s gcc gcc-4.2
```

If that doesn't do the trick (you don't have a valid version of gcc), you will need to install gcc-4.2 which comes with the [Apple developer tools](http://developer.apple.com/tools/)

You can also type `gcc` at the command line to see which versions you have installed.

Comment: I did cd /usr/bin then $ ls -l | grep gcc
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel            7 Jan  5  2011 cc -> gcc-4.0
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel            7 Jan  5  2011 gcc -> gcc-4.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel        93072 Sep 23  2007 gcc-4.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel       369408 Sep 23  2007 i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel       369408 Sep 23  2007 powerpc-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1 $ 
This means I have already the symlink though not for gcc-4.2

Comment: Thanks !! I will install gcc-4.2 and will get back !